# Wordpress - save data from own plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, save

My own wordpress plugin generates this data of a file:

filename|creator|date

```
    This is my filename|Max Mustermann|20.11.2017
    This is my filename|Anne Mustermann|26.11.2017
    This is my filename|Alex Mustermann|27.11.2017
```

How is wordpress built to save this data? How do I do that the right way?

Thanks for your answers!

Lingo

Comment: You can create a custom_type_post and use the WP posts DB structure or you can create your own DB table on the "install" event of the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example,

```html
function bot_install()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix."bot_counter";
    $structure = "CREATE TABLE $table (
        id INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        bot_name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
        bot_mark VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        bot_visits INT(9) DEFAULT 0,
 UNIQUE KEY id (id)
    );";
    $wpdb->query($structure);
 
    // Populate table
    $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO $table(bot_name, bot_mark)
        VALUES('Google Bot', 'googlebot')");
    $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO $table(bot_name, bot_mark)
        VALUES('Yahoo Slurp', 'yahoo')");
}
```

You get the result.